# get stock quote from google using phantomjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, phantomjs

I'm  trying to get the text in `span._Rnb.fmob_pr.fac-l`. I believe that is the selector for the stock quote . Right now it just returns the console `open success` skips a line or 2 then exits.

```
var webPage = require("webpage");
var page = webPage.create();
var url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=goog+stock"

page.open(url, function(status){
    console.log("open", status)
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function(status){
        // console.log($)
        var price = page.evaluate(function(){
            return $("span._Rnb").text()
            // return $(".kno-rdesc").find("span").text()
             // return  $("._Rnb").text();  
            // return  document.title       
            // return $(document).find("title").text()
        })
        console.log(price)
        phantom.exit()
    })
})
```

I don't know how to debug this. I did `console.log($)` and I got nothing.

I was able to get the h3 link tags on the page. I was wondering why I was not able to get the stock quotes.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `onConsoleMessage`, `onError`, `onResourceError`, `onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-1_phantomerrors-js)). Maybe there are errors. Kepp in mind that Google pages look differently in PhantomJS than in your desktop browser. Print the page content to see what you need.

Comment: since you said "print page content" I'm assuming doing something like this will be ok? `var content = page.content; fs.write(path, content, "w")`. I did a search for `_Rnb` in the document and none came up. It looks like the stock quote is in a `table format`. the formatting isn't good. now I need to select the item. hopefully it will work. Thanks. I didn't know there would be a big difference, like in the "print" version it is a `table`

Answer (score 0):

The selector `return $("table:nth-of-type(1) tbody > tr > td > span > b").eq(0).text()` worked.

```
page.open(url, function(status){
    console.log("open", status)
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function(status){
         var price = page.evaluate(function(){
             return $("table:nth-of-type(1) tbody > tr > td > span > b").eq(0).text()
         })
         console.log(price)
         phantom.exit()
     })
})
```

Answer (score -3):

`page.evaluate` is an asynchronous function. That means it returns immediately, before the stuff inside the function actually happens. This is logical, since page takes time to render.
However, your `console.log(price)` and, more importantly, `phantom.exit()` happen immediately.

Easiest solution is to put the `console.log` and `phantom.exit` on a long timeout (5-10 sec) to let the page evaluate properly.

More proper solution would be some sort of polling or even event passing from inside the evaluated page to the phantom.js code outside - feel free to experiment.

Comment: No, `$("span._Rnb").text()` is synchronous, so the whole `page.evaluate` call will be synchronous.